# Make a section fade on click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So the question is probably poorly worded above, however, let me try and clarify here. I have an html page that is split up into multiple sections. I have a right side and left side section and in each section I have divs that further split things up. One of these divs is called rscontent and it holds content on the right side and I have a link that once clicked must close everything in rscontent. Here is the code that does that:

```
    $('section#rightpanel').on('click', 'a#rsclose', function (event) {
    var $_closer = $(this);

    var $_sectionNav = $('header.sectionNav'); // needs to adjust size

    var $_sectionBody = $('section#body'); // needs to adjust size

    var $_rightpanel = $('section#rightpanel'); // needs to collapse this


    if ($_rightpanel.is('.collapsed')) {
        // is closed, so open it
        $_rightpanel.removeClass('collapsed').find('.rscontent').show();
        $_sectionBody.css('width', '56%');
        $_rightpanel.css('width', '34%');
        $_closer.html('Close');
    } else {
        // is open, so close it
        $_rightpanel.addClass('collapsed').find('.rscontent').hide();
        $_sectionBody.css('width', '90%');
        $_rightpanel.css('width', '2.8%');
        $_closer.html('Open');
    } // collapsed
    return false;
});
```

Now this works but my question is how can I add a fade effect so that the closing doesn't happen in a split second. I have this from my css code but I don't know how to use it.

```
    .fade {
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
 -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
 -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
 -ms-transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```

Anyone know how to do this. I hope the question makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a targeted opacity (in this case, zero)

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Add the fade class to the element you want faded out.

Vanilla

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " fade";
```

jQuery

```
$(elem).addClass("fade");
```

To trigger behavior after the fade, you can either use jQuery's .fadeOut seen here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ and add a 'complete' callback or set a timer for the duration of the fade in the CSS after adding the class.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can do fading.

Here is the jQuery documentation for [Fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/)

The `fadeToggle()` seems to be the one you are most likely interested in, here is the [fadeToggle() documentation plus examples](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Ill likely take advantage of `fadetoggle()`

Comment: Just a heads up, but I would bookmark/favorite the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) as you will wind up there a lot if you do any kind of jQuery development, I know I visit it a lot! :-)